# Calculate WACC value of stock using api

Tags: api, stock, stocks

I am planning to calculate WACC value of stock from API. Please suggest me some free API provider like yahoo finance or help me to derive Weighted average cost of capital(WACC)value from yahoo finance API.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using the SEC site itself. The following link is google's 10k: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1288776/000165204416000012/goog10-k2015.htm

The problem with WACC calculations are that they can be complex and you would have to really know what you are looking for on the balance sheet. You could possibly try https://www.barchartondemand.com/free.